# Update request URL in pre-request script

Tags: postman

Is it possible to update url of postman request in the pre-request script.
I want to edit the URL based on dynamic environment input.

For example:

```
if (environment.someValue) {
    request.url = request.url + "\" + environment.someValue
    if (environment.anotherValue) {
        request.url = request.url + "\" + environment.anotherValue
    }
}
    
console.log(request.url);
```

The above code gives me prefect console log:

e.g. if url is `https://someServer/someRequest`, `environment.someVar` is `x` and `environment.anotherVar` is `y` the `console.log(request.url)` above prints:

```
https://someServer/someRequest/x/y
```

But the problem is (say if i am requesting a Get), even after logging the overridden request url, it only calls `https://someServer/someRequest` and does not override to `https://someServer/someRequest/x/y`.

Any ideas how to modify the url as asked above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the URL in your request is set as global, it should work.
E.g. I have a GET request:

`GET http://{{myurl}}/etc.` with `myurl` set to a global variable.

In my pre-request script I do `pm.globals.set("myurl", <new url>);`

When I launch the request, it tries to do a GET request on my new URL.

So it is possible to do but you have to use global or environment variables to dynamically update your request:

set your `'someRequest'` as a global that you can update in your prescript (instead of `request.url`), then it will be interpreted when you launch your request:

```
https://someServer/{{someRequest}}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
pm.request.url = "dynamic value"
```

You can update the URL using the above single line in a Postman pre-request step.

`pm.request.url` returns a object with fields `host`, `path`, and `params` . But you can replace it with a string.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out but in my case the first solution by A.Joly is more useful due to code readability, the one you have suggested would be of more use if the entire url is dynamic and I appreciate/upvote the fact that you have highlighted this solution :)

Comment: Sure , the previous answer allowed only part of url to be change , I answered it so that someone could use to change entire url before sending the request

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips: I used these lines of code to manipulate two values that appear in a RESTful API route:

// Ensure Payroll ID and Employee ID in request URL are correctly padded with zeros
pm.request.url.path[pm.request.url.path.indexOf("{{PayrollID}}")] = data.PayrollID.toString().padStart(6, '0');
pm.request.url.path[pm.request.url.path.indexOf("{{EmployeeID}}")] = data.EmployeeID.toString().padStart(7, '0');